# Connectivity issues while chaining TL-SG108E switches with simple configuration (no VLAN)

Tags: home-networking, switch

Due to the architecture of my house, I have to chain switches. I bought 3 managed TP link on Amazon TL-SG108E switches to have a proper configuration in the future, but right now it does not work.

To add more info

- I have only managed switches TL-SG108E : two v3 and one V2.
- I have 3 because I have to connect basement to First floor; then to
  second floor.
- I have computer science background (15 years ago); so I get the
  basics but I have no applied experience here
- I bought managed because those were super cheap for 1G 8 ports, and
  plus eventually I want to setup QoS
- I bought them because In french there's an expression "who can do
  more can do less"
- I dont need VLANs

To talk about configuration I did after I reset the switches:

- ISP box is a Fritzbox 7490 with stock configuration -> this is
  normally the only DHCP server; IP address is 192.168.178.1
- Only 1 port is used of the ISP Box and goes to the 1st switch
- The Wifi is enabled and used
- I have recent cables - at least cat 5e cables
- I made sure I used the latest available firmware for all 3
- I assigned a static and unused IP addresses to each, gateway to the
  IP of the Box for all switches DHCP is deactivated for all switches
- I wrote down the MAC address to not make any mistakes
- I did a factory reset of my ISP box - just in case
- I did not want to activate VLAN ,but it seems in the interface that I
  have to leave one enabled at least: MTU / Port based / 802.1Q

This is looking like:
ISP box ---> Switch "basement (v3) —> Switch "TV" (v2) —> Switch "Desktop" (v3)

About what’s connected:

- switch basement —> I have a NAS, and a computer
- Switch TV  -> I have TV, playstation, TV box , Apple TV, and a laptop
  I can plug
- Switch desk -> two computers, Apple TV

Here are my findings

- There’s internet at the switch basement. All is OK
- There’s not internet from switch TV (all devices connected to TV and Desktop)
- If I unplug the Desktop switch —> nothing change
- If I switch the TV and Desktop; same results --> here I was suspecting a conflict with V2 and V3.
- If I replace the switch TV by an unmanaged switch -> I have internet everywhere
- From the PC connected to switches TV and Desktop -> I never see the switch basement -- But I suspect this is because I am not connected to it directly although that's not the same bevavior as if I use the PC connected to desktop;
- I see both desktop and TV switches

Hope that makes sense to someone… I am quite lost; It seems like Switch basement is OK but somehow is not able to talk to another manager switch I have.

Comment: This sounds very suspect of an IP address conflict... What if you disconnect everything except the switches and one PC off of desktop switch, can you access everything? If not, go back one level and connect the same PC to TV switch. Remember you said they got these because they were "super cheap", maybe you just got a dud? It sounds like all 3 switches are identical except for IP address, try switching them around a bit.

Comment: And there is zero need for VLANs in this scenario, unless I am missing something, and adding that level of complexity here would just make it more difficult to troubleshoot, and they are not needed to do QoS in a home network, you just need a quality router.

Comment: Correct, as mentioned I don't need VLAN , but there's by default a generic config a port-based VLAN on all switches.

Comment: tried already to switch them and minimize the devices connected, there's no conflicts of IP. the switch located at the "basement" location always works, and the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

At last, it works. The error was one of the long cable that was not working if put between 2 managed switches, but as soon as there was the unmanaged switch this was working. Somehow the managed switches don’t tolerate some cable issues very well.

hard stuff (hard to replace a 15m cable going through walls) but now all is ok.